# Dragging items and changing their order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-sortable

**BACKGROUND**

I am basically parsing data that contains some team name and and its respective id. For instance my raw data looks like this --> teamName(MIAMI HEAT, id1) teamName(NewYork Knicks, id2).

I have parsed this kind of data  according to my needs. So once user logins they are taken to welcome page which contains a nav menu on the side that will display the names of various teams i parsed earlier like Miami Heat, NewYork Knicks etc. I also create dynamic pages for each team on the nav menu. So for instance if you click on Miami Heat you are taken to a page www.something.com/index.html#id1

So in this case for Miami Heat page the page id is id1 as it was earlier in the raw data.

**This is what i want to achieve**

So basically on my welcome page where i have a nav menu containing all the various teams i am currently able to drag and drop them. So for instance if my nav menu contains 
Miami,
Toronto 
NewYork. 
I can drag Toronto on top so the order in the nav menu canges to
Toronto
Miami
NewYork

I was wondering can i have this reflect on the actual order of the pages. so if I drag Toronto on the top and when i swipe left Toronto should appear. If i drag NewYork on top then when i swipe left NewYork should appear.

Can someone please give me guidance on how to achieve this and is is it even possible? Sorry if this is a bad question i am a noob in js world.  Please pardon me as i am self learning js.

**PS: i am currently able to swipe but its a random order and not responsive to the drag and drop function.**

**UPDATED CODE AGAIN**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <TITLE>BASKETBALL FANATICO</TITLE>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.flatui.css" />
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
    <!-- TEST Jquery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.countdown.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

    <!-- Style.css  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">

    <!-- Testing Drag -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>BASKETBALL FANATICO</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="loginfo">
              <h2>Please Enter the Login Credentials</h2>
            </div>
            <form method="GET">
                <div id="username" data-role="fieldcontain">     
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" />
                </div>
                <div id="password" data-role="fieldcontain">   
                   <input type="password" name="password" id="txtId" placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>
                <div id ="loginbtn">
                    <a data-role="button" id="log" data-theme="b" href="#page2" data-transition="slide">Login</a>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>NBA</h1>
            </div>    
        </div>

        <!-- page 2 -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page2">
            <div data-role="header" data-positiion="fixed">
                <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#panel" data-role="button" data-icon="flat-menu"></a>
                <h1>BASKETBALL FANATICO</h1>
                <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#page2" data-role="button" data-icon="home" title="Home">Home</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content"> 
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b">WELCOME!</li>
                    <li>Use the menu on the left to navigate <br />and configure the various options.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div data-role="panel" id="panel"  data-position="left" data-theme="a" data-display="push">
            <div>
                <div id="nav"><h3>Navigation Menu</h3></div>
                <label>
                <input id="chkSort" type="checkbox" checked="true"  />Allow sorting</input>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div id="items" data-role="button">
                <!-- Insert Parsed Teams Here -->
                <a href="#page1" data-transition="fade" data-theme="b" data-role="button">LOG OUT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script>
        var teamNames = new Array();
        var teamId = new Array();

        $( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
            $( "body > [data-role='panel']" ).panel().enhanceWithin();
        });

        $(document).on('pagecreate', '#page1', function() {

            $("#log").on('click', function(){
                alert('hellow');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://1xx.1xx.0.1xx:8081/script.login",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { 'page':'create_user', 'access':'user','username':$("input[name='username']").val(), 'password':$("input[name='password']").val()},
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function (html) {
                            console.log(html);
                            console.log('==============>TESTING');

                            teamNames = new Array();
                            teamId = new Array();
                            var res = html.match(/teamNames(.*);/g);

                            for(var i =0;i<res.length;i++){
                                //alert(res[i]);
                                var temp = res[i].split(',');
                                if(temp.length >= 3){
                                  teamNames[i] = (temp[2].replace('");','')).replace('"','');
                                  teamId[i] = temp[1].replace("'","").replace("'","").replace(/ /g,'');
                                }           
                            }

                            var AllTeams = ''
                            for(var i = 0; i<teamNames.length; i++){
                                AllTeams +='<a href="#'+teamId[i]+'" class="teamLink" data-theme="b" data-role="button" >'+teamNames[i]+'</a>';                         
                                var makePage = $("<div data-role='page' id='"+teamId[i]+"' data-pageindex='"+i+"' class='dynPageClass'><div data-role='header' data-position='fixed'><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#panel' data-role='button' data-icon='flat-menu'></a><h1>BASKETBALL FANATICO</h1><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#page2' data-role='button' data-icon='home' title='Home'>Home</a></div> <div data-role='content'><ul data-role='listview'data-insert='true'><li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='b'>"+teamNames[i]+"</li><li><h2>0</h2></li></ul></div><div data-role='footer' data-position='fixed'><span class='ui-title'><div id='navigator'></div></span></div></div>");

                                makePage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
                            }
                            $('#items').prepend(AllTeams).trigger('create');
                        }
                });
            });
        });

        $(document).on('pagecreate', '#page2', function() {

            $("#items").sortable({
                  stop: function( event, ui ) {
                      teamNames = [];
                      teamId = [];
                      $(".teamLink").each(function() {
                          var href = $(this).prop('href');
                          var name = $(this).text();
                          var id = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
                          teamId.push(id);
                          teamNames.push(name)
                      });
                      alert(teamNames);
                      $("#items").listview('refresh');
                  }
            }).disableSelection();

            $("#chkSort").on("change", function(){
                var sort = $(this).prop("checked");
                if (sort){
                    $( "#items" ).sortable('enable');
                } else {
                    $("#items").sortable('disable');
                }

            });

            $(document).on("swipeleft", "#page2", function() {
               $.mobile.changePage("#"+teamId[0], {transition: "slide", reverse: false});
            });        

            $(document).on("swiperight swipeleft", ".dynPageClass", function(e) {
                var curPageID = $(this).prop("id");
                var ind=0;
                for(var i = 0; i<teamId.length; i++){
                    if (curPageID == teamId[i]){
                        ind = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                var topageid = "page2";
                var rev = true;
                if (e.type == 'swiperight'){
                    if (ind > 0){
                        topageid = teamId[ind - 1] ; 
                    }
                } else {
                    rev = false;
                    if (ind < teamId.length - 1){
                        topageid = teamId[ind + 1] ; 
                    }            
                }
                $.mobile.changePage("#" + topageid, {transition: "slide", reverse: rev});
            });         

        });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any html/js code, or screenshots will be helpfull

Comment: sure i will post my code, just give me 2 minutes. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης, i just posted the code.

Comment: i see you have a mistake in your ajax call, you close the success function and then you start a for loop withing the object, check it please. Also see I formatted your code, you should keep that for other developers to actually understand easier what your code does

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης Thanks for the edit, any suggestions on how i can achieve my desired result?

Comment: I told you before you have problem with your script code, see your ajax call

Comment: It's working fine for me though...

Comment: Basically, each time the user drags a team to a new position, you need to rebuild the teamId and teamNames arrays in the new order, that way when the swipe code checks for next or previous index in the array it will find the correct one for that order.

Comment: @ezanker How do you change the array based on drag though? I am not understanding how to rebuild teamId in new order? because there is no connection piece between the drag function and the teamName and teamId Array. Also if you can post as answer i want to vote you up you have been so much helpful to me.

Comment: @ezanker hey i just posted a question, if u got some free time please take look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sortable function of jQueryUI provides a stop event which fires every time sorting has finished. So in that event handler you iterate through the teams in the new order and rebuild the arrays which should be global variable on the page.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/10/)** (based on fiddles from your other questions)

Your arrays are declared outside of any functions so they are global.

```
var teamNames = new Array();
var teamId = new Array();
```

First, when adding teams to the list you are using prepend() because you want to keep the existing log out button at the bottom of list. That makes your teams show in reverse order from the array.  To correct this, you can add the teams like this:

```
var AllTeams = ''
for(var i = 0; i < teamNames.length; i++){
    AllTeams +='<a href="#'+teamId[i]+'" class="teamLink" data-theme="b" data-role="button" >'+teamNames[i]+'</a>';
}
$('#items').prepend(AllTeams).trigger('create');
```

You are adding all the teams to a string variable in correct order and then finally prepending the whole collection once. **NOTE: I added a class called teamLink to each link so I can easily iterate them after sorting.**

Then the sortable part:

```
$("#items").sortable({
      stop: function( event, ui ) {
          teamNames = [];
          teamId = [];
          $(".teamLink").each(function() {
              var href = $(this).prop('href');
              var name = $(this).text();
              var id = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
              teamId.push(id);
              teamNames.push(name)
          });
          $("#items").listview('refresh');
      }
}).disableSelection();
```

In the stop callback, you first empty the 2 global arrays, then iterate all links with class teamLink. Get the id from the href and the team name from the text and rebuild the arrays. In the fiddle I have added an alert that displays the new array after each sort so you can see the new order.

NOTE: In the code in your question, teamID and teamNames is misspelled in some places. Also you could make the pages in the same loop that adds the links to the panel.

Comment: Thanks so much.  i made the changes you suggested so i am able to see the team name change order. so now to make the swipe function utilize this change do i call the AllTeams array instead of the other two inside the swipe function?

Comment: Hey i actually just noticed that in my nav menu items are repeating now like the first item is also repeated. example -> miami,houston,newyork,miami.  for some reason miami is showing up twice now. should i post the code? maybe u can see what i did wrong

Comment: Actually swipe code will change because we stored page index in the page. Instead we should get the id and figure out the current index. Here is the updated fiddle with makepage and swipe code: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/11/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time and i read your last comment and upon looking at your fidle i made changes . However after making those changes i still have some problems. One problem is for example if i have a list of teams -> miami,toronto,houston. then in the nav menu the teams will show as miami,toronto,houston,houston,toronto,miami.
Also it is not swiping in the changed order for some reason. I am sure i have made changes wrong so if you can please point out our even edit my code thanks so much.

Comment: i added my edit as a new code section in your question. You were adding the teams twice (once the old way and once the new way). I also arranged your code better and put it in the correct page events.  I just edited by hand and did not test, so there could be some typos...

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Yea i took your edited code there were couple of small typos but other than it works perfectly fine but there is one small problem for some odd reason. when i swipe from welcome screen to go to the first dynamically generated page it seems to skip over it and go to the 2nd dynamically generated page. Any reasons as to why that could be?

Comment: i see the problem, remove class="dynPageClass" from page2

Comment: hey Just had a quick question. I have a nav menu panel on my 2nd page and i just realized i did not add the panel in the dynamically generated pages so i just tried to add it . The panel loads fine on the dynamically generated pages however the names of teams are not loading. So for example on the welcome page when i opne nav menu i will have -->miami,newyork,toronto,logout. and when i open the nav menu on the dynamically generated pages i nly have the logout button but none of the parsed names of teams appear.

Comment: I posted the code under the title updated code so if you could look that it would be very helpful.

Comment: Use external panel: move panel markup outside page, in dynamic pages only have menu button link to the panel id, and init the panel in code. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/12/ I also edited the code in your question.

Comment: Perfect, Just Wondering how did you manage to change that allow sorting box first it was a different it was more like a button.

Comment: External panels don't automatically enhance markup, to get the jQM looking checkbox add enhanceWithin() to the panel initialization, $( "body > [data-role='panel']" ).panel().enhanceWithin();  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/14/

Comment: That is so cool! Thanks so much learned so much from you. do you have a blog or something? i wana learn more jquery stuff

Comment: No I don't blog.  I find answering StackOverflow questions is actually a good way to learn. Although I had jQuery experience, I was new jQM in September, so by answering people's questions and making fiddles I have learned a lot.

Comment: Hey, I had a question regarding how to parse certain response body. Its based on the same jquery app i am working on so i thought if you would be intrested in helping me out . if you can then i can post it as seprate question. Thanks again.